# Use a value of a var to dynamically build a class name

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to do something like this. One can import something like:
`from random import randint`
and then later assign it  like:
`x = randint()`

and what I'm trying to do is try to find a way to dynamically set any value:
`var x = myint`

and use that VALUE to assign to the class instead... like
`(the value of x) = randint()`

so if you printed:
`print(type(myint))`

you'd see:
`>>>  (class random.randint)`

Not sure if I'm making any sense but...in php, one just has to do something like @x to make it use the value of the variable and not just reassign the variable. So it would end up like:

```
x= "myvar"
@x = randint()
print(type(myvar))
>>> (class random.randint)
```

and then be able to do whatever you wanted later like:

```
new_int = myvar.randint(0, 50)
```

Something like that...is what I'm shooting for even possible?

Comment: What does `@` do in PHP other than suppressing error messages??? Not sure what your purpose is, but you can simply do `myvar = randint` and then `myvar(0, 50)` to generate a random integer. Also `randint` is a method, not a class, so it's not possible to see `class random.randint` as your output.

Comment: Don't. Don't do that. It's a terrible practice. There is *never a good reason to do this*. I would just abandon everything you learned in PHP if you are writing Python.

Comment: I actually put the functionality inside a def statement and got it working...I apologize for not coming back here to mark as solved. As for the @ in php...it transfers the VALUE of the variable to the assignment...i.e. myvar = 123 makes the variable myvar = 123...whereas myvar= "test", and then @myvar = 123   instead of myvar having the value of 123, now it would be test = 123.   

But the way I did it in my python code worked perfectly and I TOTALLY respected the "python way" :)